# commands not working in remote server with SSH

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, expect

I am trying to run a shell script having expect code in it for ssh login.

I am able to log into the remote server but not able to execute any commands on the remote server instead code is getting executed on the local machine through which shell script is executed.

I am using the below approach of running an expect from a shell as I need to take values from three files (host,username and password) and them in the same script.
Please find the code below:

```
**array function for creating an array and storing the file content in it. **
getArray "password.txt" //for getting data from file to array
for e in "${array[@]}" //password getting stored in 
do
    echo "$e"
/usr/bin/expect << EOD
spawn ssh abc@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
sleep 5
expect "Password:"
sleep 5
send "$e\n"  //sending password
sleep 5
interact
expect "[abc@servername ~]"  //this is the text observed after logging into remote server
sleep 5
send "ls -lrt"  // trying to get file list from remote 
sleep 5
interact
sleep 5
EOD
sleep 5
ls -lrt
echo "you are out"
sleep 5
ls -lrt
done
```

*************************************output************************************

I am able to log into the remote server but getting below output for "`ls -lrt`"

```
$ invalid command name "abc@servername"
    while executing
"abc@servername ~"
    invoked from within
"expect "[abc@servername ~]""
total 24
```

file list shown for my local machine
you are out
file list shown for my local machine

Kindly let me know if there is any modification required / another approach for the above code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to use SSH keys to bypass the password challenge? Set up the keys, then just `ssh user@remoteserver ls -lrt`. SSH keys are WAY better security than cleartext passwords stored in files, and if you can avoid using an `expect` script by simply sending the command you want to the remote server, you eliminate loads of complexity.

Comment: I need to run shell script which will do ssh into multiple servers (credentials will be fetched through the text file) That is why i need expect in my script.

Comment: I would suggest that what you need is to copy your management server's ssh public key (`.ssh/id_rsa.pub` for example) into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on each of the target servers. Use your tools properly, it will simplify your life.